# Can I Rename sites in WebMatrix?

Tags: webmatrix

I am playing around with Umbraco which I install though the Web Platform Installer. 3 different sites are now showing up in WebMatrix, and they are just Umbraco CMS1, Umbraco CMS2 and Umbraco CMS3. Is there a way to change that name? It's pretty confusing at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the applicationhost.config file (My Documents > IISExpress > config) and change the site name there.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually rename sites by opening the site in WebMatrix, going to the Site workspace, right-clicking the site folder item in the left pane tree, and choosing **Rename**.

Note that this does not change the folder name, only the entry in applicationhost.config file.

Comment: If once you have renamed it you delete the old folders inside the folder with the applicationhost.config file both inside "PublishUI" & "Web Deploy" then it will recreate them with the correct name (if it hasn't already recreated them). Really only for those of us that have errr issues with things being right! ;P But lets face it you found this question cause of that right?